# Stripe webhook checkout.session items to Supabase

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments, supabase, supabase-database

Im using next.js and Stripe webhooks to insert checkout sessions to Supabase that will create a customer's order history.  I'm able to get the information about the whole order written to a table called 'orders', but am wondering what the best way to add individual items within each checkout session to another table called 'order_items' is.  This way I can map through main orders and then the children items. Appreciate any help provided. Here is what I have for getting orders associated with a customer:

```
const upsertOrderRecord = async (session: Stripe.Checkout.Session, customerId: string) => {
  const { data: customerData, error: noCustomerError } = await supabaseAdmin
    .from<Customer>('customers')
    .select('id')
    .eq('stripe_customer_id', customerId)
    .single();
  if (noCustomerError) throw noCustomerError;

  const { id: uuid } = customerData || {};
    const sessionData: Session = {
      id: session.id,
      amount_total: session.amount_total ?? undefined,
      user_id: uuid ?? undefined
    };

    const { error } = await supabaseAdmin.from<Session>('orders').insert([sessionData], { upsert: true });
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(`Product inserted/updated: ${session.id}`);
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

The Checkout Session object contains a [`line_items` field](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items) which is a list of each item included in the purchase.

However this field is **not** included in the object by default, and therefore won't be a part of your webhook payload. Instead you'll need to make an API call in your webhook handle to [retrieve](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) the Checkout Session object, passing the [`expand` parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) to include the `line_items` field:

```js
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve('cs_test_xxx', {
  expand: ['line_items']
});
```

Comment: Here's what I have for webhook. Any idea how to make this expansion work?  Appreciate the help.

         `case 'checkout.session.completed':
            const checkoutSession = event.data
              .object as Stripe.Checkout.Session;
            await upsertOrderRecord(event.data.object as Stripe.Checkout.Session, checkoutSession.customer as string,);
            break;`

Comment: As stated, you can't use the `event.data.object` directly as it won't contain the `line_items` field you need. You'll need to make an additional API request to Stripe in your webhook handler, using the `id` of the Checkout Session (which is in the event payload). There you can pass the `expand` parameter (see code example in my answer). The response to that API call will contain the `line_items` field.